# Умножение матриц разной размерности

Tags: c#, матрицы

Как умножить матрицу на матрицу разной размерности?
У меня есть матрицы `[200,3]` и `[3,3]`. Можно ли их перемножить?

Comment: Для матриц A * B != B * A, поэтому укажите в каком порядке производится умножение

Comment: Матрицы такого вида: http://kompgraflab.ru/attachments/Image/form4_lab3.jpg
x0,..x200 , y0,..y200.

Answer (score 2):

Операция умножения двух матриц А и В определяется только для случая, когда ЧИСЛО СТОЛБЦОВ МАТРИЦЫ А РАВНО ЧИСЛУ СТРОК МАТРИЦЫ В. Это чисто математическое ограничение. Точка. Так что ответ - нет, нельзя.

P.S. Поспешил и толком не глянул на размерности. Умножение в общем-то происходит достаточно просто, например как тут: 
http://www.webmath.ru/poleznoe/formules_6_6.php

Comment: можно перемножить наоборот, автор же не обозначил в каком порядке он их собирается перемножать =)

Comment: А, ну да, коммутативность умножения работает в таком случае. Тупанул